# Additional GS1 codes support in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

We need to add support for GS1 Barcode *Customer Part Number*  in the Purchases - Receive and Put Away screen, it is not supported by default and I can't a find a way to add it.

From looking at the source code, it seems like I need to override `GS1Support` property or the `GetGS1ApplicationSteps()` method on `PX.Objects.PO.WMS.ReceivePutAway` class but I can't find a way to to this. I tried to override using PXGraphExtension method:

```
public class ReceivePutAway_Extension : PXGraphExtension<ReceivePutAway>
{
      
}
```

but then I get the following error:

*CS0311 The type 'PX.Objects.PO.WMS.ReceivePutAway' cannot be used as type parameter 'Graph' in the generic type or method 'PXGraphExtension'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'PX.Objects.PO.WMS.ReceivePutAway' to 'PX.Data.PXGraph'* class.

**UPDATE:**

After updating the extension class declaration as suggested, now the error is gone but I'm still unable to find a way to override `GetGS1ApplicationSteps()` method on the BLC extension class `PX.Objects.PO.WMS.ReceivePutAway`, .

Does anybody know how to make the override work for a class like this or maybe has good suggestion on how to add support for additional GS1 barcodes?

Answer (score 0):

ReceivePutAway is not a Graph, therefore you cannot do a simple Graph Extension directly on it. ReceivePutAway inherits from WMSBase which is actually defined as a Graph Extension. This means that you need to end up with a second level graph extension.

If you need to customize ReceivePutAway, I would suggest to try the approach mentioned here:
https://help-2021r1.acumatica.com/(W(1))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=c86fdae8-fef9-4490-aa57-3528d0fa172e

Refer to section 'Second-Level BLC Extension' in the above link. In your case, it might be something like this:

```
 public class ExtensioReceivePutAway_Extension :
      PXGraphExtension<ReceivePutAway, ReceivePutAwayHost>
    {
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the error. I still need to override the GetGS1ApplicationSteps() method on ReceivePutAway, any ideas?

Comment: I think GetGS1ApplicationSteps i s in graph extension WarehouseManagementSystemGraph. You could try to modify this extension using the approach in my reply and then override the GetGS1ApplicationSteps method.